# derivative and value of a polynomial having symbolic coefficients

Tags: matlab, polynomial-math, derivative

![enter image description here][1]I have an unknown equation of a curve `y = a0 + a1*x + a2*x^2 +....+ a9*x^9` where coefficients are symbolic. I want to find its derivative and its values on particular xi.

```
xi = 0:01:10;    

syms a0 a1 a2 a3 a4 a5 a6 a7 a8 a9

y = [a0 a1 a2 a3 a4 a5 a6 a7 a8 a9];
dy = polyder(y);
val_y = polyval(y,xi);
val_dy = polyval(dy,xi);
```

Then I have to do some more mathematical operations with the result and compare with the known final answer so that I can find out the value of this unknown coefficients.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: So what is your question? If you want to find the coefficients a0~a9 from some datasets [xi, yi, dyi] i=1..n. Then it is a linear regression problem.

Comment: @ysakamoto: I have to find equation of normal lines to this unknown curve at `xi` and intersection of this normal lines with other known curve. I know the point where it should intersect. So i can find out the coefficients from their.

Comment: Please edit your question so that it asks a specific question. Also, `polyder` doesn't appear to support symbolic inputs – don't you get an error?

Comment: This is still not clear. Can you just explain thoroughly, using the figure, what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

Isn't it more of a math problem then? The line that is tangent to a curve y=f(x) at point x0 has a slope (1, f'(x0)). The vector from the point (x0, f(x0)) to another point (x1, y1) is (x1-x0, y1-f(x0)). Then the equation to solve is:

```
dot([x1-x0, y1-f(x0)], [1, diff(f(x0),x0)]) = 0
```

If f is a 9th degree polynomial, a0~a9 values cannot be determined from just the equation above.

Comment: I added a picture. The equation for the final and initial stages are known to me. Also the points on the initial curve from where I am dropping the normal is also known. Also, I know the final points on the final curve where the intersection should meet. My aim is to find out the intermediate 2 curve equations.

Comment: Also the lines you can see between the curves are normal to the previous curve.